# Empty boxplot in R

Tags: r, boxplot

I am trying to draw boxplots with the following code. When I run it, I get 2 empty boxes, with no plot. It must be something minor, but I can't seem to fix it. Can someone please help.

Sorry, just added the library as 1st line of code.

Here's my code:

```
library(HSAUR3)   
data(schizophrenia2)

layout(matrix(1:2, nrow =1))
ylim <- range(schizophrenia2$month)
Less <- subset(schizophrenia2, onset == "< 20 Years")
More <- subset(schizophrenia2, onset == "> 20 Years")

boxplot(month ~ disorder, data = Less, ylab = "Month",
    xlab = "Disorder", ylim = ylim, main = "Less than 20")

boxplot(month ~ disorder, data = More, ylab = "Month",
    xlab = "Disorder", ylim = ylim, main = "More than 20")
```

Comment: Where does the schizophrenia2 data come from. We cannot reproduce your code without the data

Comment: @JRR Package `HSAUR`. Found it with `library(sos); findFn("schizophrenia2")`. Package `sos` is a must.

Comment: This is just a typo. `onset == "< 20 Years"` should in fact be `onset == "< 20 yrs"`. Voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Rui Barradas. It worked like a charm!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Less <- subset(schizophrenia2, onset == "< 20 yrs")
More <- subset(schizophrenia2, onset == "> 20 yrs")
```